# How to choose how to fetch relationships from a relational database?

Tags: sql

I know of at least 4 ways of fetching relationships from a relational database.
I tried to make the examples generic to any language.

I'd like to know some algorithm of choosing one over the other besides manually testing the query.

**Method A**: has the problem of having to loop twice to build the result. also can't process one row at a time one by one without building arrays.

```
for contact in query("SELECT id, name FROM contact") {

    contacts[contact.id]["name"] = contact.name
    push(ids, contact.id)

}

for email in query("SELECT contact_id, address FROM email WHERE contact_id IN ?", ids) {

    push(contacts[email.contact_id]["emails"], email.address)

}
```

**Method B**: Has the problem of a cartesian join in case of more joins

```
for contact in query("SELECT c.id, c.name, e.address FROM contact c JOIN email e ON e.contact_id = c.id") {

    contacts[contact.id]["name"] = contact.name
    push(contacts[email.contact_id]["emails"], email.address)

}
```

**Method C**: Has a problem in that GROUP_CONCAT is limited to a certain number of bytes and might be cut off

```
for contact in query("SELECT c.id, c.name, GROUP_CONCAT(e.address) AS addresses FROM contact c JOIN email e ON e.contact_id = c.id GROUP BY c.id") {

    contacts[contact.id]["name"] = contact.name
    contacts[contact.id]["emails"] = split(",", contact.addresses)
}
```

**Method D**: Has the N+1 query problem, runs a query for each contact

```
contactStatement = prepare("SELECT id, name FROM contact")
emailStatement = prepare("SELECT address FROM email WHERE contact_id = ?")

for contact in contactStatement.query() {

    contacts[contact.id]["name"] = contact.name

    // this uses a prepared query
    for email in emailStatement.query(contact.id) {
        push(contacts[contact.id]["emails"], email.address)
    }

}
```

Or maybe there is a way that is ideal in every case?
I have many years of experience using various ORM's and I'd like to avoid using one.

Method A is what most ORM's default to.
Method D is what seems like the solution that SQL designers expect us to use.

I'm asking for some help in how to find a logical way of picking one method over another for a specific SQL query.

Comment: Definitely not C and D. A and B is what we mainly use. Choosing between A and B depends on the size of the table, how often we access it and also on the indexes. We try to avoid more than one join in any circumstances as our tests showed a significant performance drop when dealing with 100K rows.

Comment: Why not using B ? But instead use something like paging with limits. So you would get the first `X entries`, and if the developer's code called `next()` specifically `X times`, it would call the next page. I think hibernate in java uses proxy wrapper objects that do stuff like this underneath for lazy loading. However, you still have the cost of a cartesian product.

Comment: I know that each one of these might be good for a certain situation, I was wondering how to choose one over another in a certain situation, @KaleshKaladharan mentions that if you have only one join then B works, otherwise they use A and never C or D.

Comment: As I mentioned, it depends on various factors and the kind of data we are dealing with. B won't hurt you that big, if you limit the query resultset to few numbers as quoted by @MenelaosBakopoulos